# Filter XML output between 2 wildcards with Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I want to filter text from a XML file for the enduser between 2 wildcards (= and ,).

The XML file:

```
<OPTIONS Product="Testing" Version="1.1">
 <Domains>
  <Domain Name="domain.local">
   <Path>OU=Test1,OU=Users,OU=HQ,DC=domain,DC=local</Path>
  </Domain>
  <Domain Name="domain.local">
   <Path>OU=Test2,OU=Users,OU=HQ,DC=domain,DC=local</Path>
  </Domain>
</OPTIONS>
```

My Powershell code so far:

```
[xml]$optionsfile = Get-Content C:\test\options.xml

foreach( $ou in $optionsfile.Options.Domains.Domain )
{
    $ou.Path
}
```

**Now I want to show only the text between the first "=" and first "," of the XML file**
. So the output will be:

Test1
Test2

etc...

I do not want to use

```
$ou.Path | select-string -pattern "Test1"
```

But filter the text between the 2 wildcards.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract it with a regex. It looks for 'OU=' from the beginning of the string, then it puts everything that is not a comma in a capture group ($1), then it replaces the whole string with the captured text.

```
$ou.Path -replace '^OU=([^,]+).+$','$1'
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response & explanation!